# multiple clients broadcast to server in same port

Tags: java, sockets, udp, broadcast, datagram

i am building a client server program, and i want to simulate having clients to send to the servers that can connect to each other in the same ipv4 "255.255.255.255" and i have specific ports to work on: the port 30381 must have the servers if its possible. what is the best solution to make this since i want to run the same program multiple times?

i have this in the code but is not working well  it connects same program client-server but not to other programs:

client:

```
        datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(30382);
        datagramSocket.setBroadcast(true);
        this.ipDest = InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255");

        byte[] data = new byte[512];
        DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length,ipDest, 30381);
        datagramSocket.send(request);
        DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        datagramSocket.receive(reply);
        this.ipDest = reply.getAddress();
        // do something with the reply
```

server:

```
        this.datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(null);
        this.datagramSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(30381));
        while (true) {
        DatagramPacket request= new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        this.datagramSocket.receive(request);
        clientIP = pedido.getAddress();
        clientPort = pedido.getPort();
        System.out.println(clientPort);

        //write list 

        DatagramPacket reply= new DatagramPacket(list.getBytes(),list.length(), clientIP, clientPort);
        this.datagramSocket.send(reply);
    }
```

im sorry if this is question is not very well, im new to this page.

Comment: mm not very clear what you're trying to do. If you want multiple clients connecting to a single server that's possible (just put a while(true) in your server code). If you want multiple servers listening on the same port that's not possible.

Comment: For UDP (Multicasts), multiple applications can subscribe to the same port. so i can do it use the same port but different ip.but i dont know if im doing it right

Comment: and i have a while(true) in server code @gidim

Comment: 255.255.255.255 is not a true address, it is an (outdated) broadcast ip. I really have no idea what you are asking about.

Comment: @SergeyA i want all server to be in the same network and they can be connected by the ipv4 255.255.255.255. so the clients can get the datagrams from all the servets